# Using If/Else With Timer Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, timer

I'm currently making a timer which starts on tap and stops on tap, but the timer is displayed like this:
0:0.00 (Mins:Secs.MilliSec). I want to make it so that when the timer reaches 1 min, that's when the min section shows. i would think that this is done by using if else. Here a link to my timer [look](https://github.com/HunterColly/Speed-Cuber/blob/master/lib/widgets/timer_clock.dart), and timer [page](https://github.com/HunterColly/Speed-Cuber/blob/master/lib/Screens/Timer.dart). Thanks Hunter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use an if condition in the colection of rows to eliminate `0s`

```
return new Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[
    if (currentTime.minutes > 0) new Container(
      child: new SizedBox(
        height: 100.0,
        child: new Text(
          '${currentTime.minutes.toString()}:',
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 90.0,
              fontFamily: 'Quicksand',
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Color(0xFF00FFFF)
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    if (currentTime.seconds > 0)  new Container(
      child: new SizedBox(
        height: 100.0,
        child: new Text(
          '${currentTime.seconds.toString()}.',
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 90.0,
              fontFamily: 'Quicksand',
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Color(0xFF00FFFF)
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    new Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 0, 0),
      child: new SizedBox(
        height: 80.0,
        child: new Text(
          currentTime.hundreds.toString().padLeft(2, '0'),
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 70.0,
              fontFamily: 'Quicksand',
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Color(0xFF00FFFF)
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```